# Serve JSON Data from Github Pages

Tags: json, api, github, repository, github-pages

I have a repository on github which contains a number of csv, json, yml data files in the root directory of the repository.

How do I get it to serve those files using Github Pages?

So for eg: when I go to `http://username.github.io/reponame/` followed by

- `/posts` - serve the contents of the **posts.json** file
- `/users` - serve the contents of the **users.json** file
- `/comments` - serve the contents of the **comments.json** file
- `/posts.csv` - serve the contents of the **posts.csv** file

Answer (score 25):

You just need to add `.json` files in your repository and you can access them like a normal JSON API

In the repository `username.github.io/reponame` add the following files

**posts.json**

```
[
  {"id": 1, "title": "Title 1"},
  {"id": 2, "title": "Title 2"}
]
```

**users.json**

```
[
  {"name": "abc", "email": "abc@example.com"},
  {"name": "xyz", "email": "xyz@example.com"}
]
```

**comments.json**

```
[
  {"post_id": "1", "text": "Comment 1"},
  {"post_id": "2", "text": "Comment 2"}
]
```

**posts.csv**

```
id,title
1,Title 1
2,Title 2
```

And access them with

- **`http://username.github.io/reponame/posts.json`**
- **`http://username.github.io/reponame/users.json`**
- **`http://username.github.io/reponame/comments.json`**
- **`http://username.github.io/reponame/posts.csv`**

Working example -

- https://deepakmahakale.github.io/api/users.json

Comment: I did this but it is taking a long time to fetch some 10k entries is there a faster way?

Answer (score 9):

You can create `index.json` instead of `index.html` to get `application/json; charset=utf-8` header.

That is, create:
- `posts/index.json` to be served at `http://username.github.io/reponame/posts/`,
- `users/index.json` to be served at `http://username.github.io/reponame/users/`,
etc.

Note that as a directory, access without trailing slash (`http://username.github.io/reponame/posts`) returns 301 redirect to same path with trailing slash.  That is, it works but your client need to follow redirects (`curl` by default doesn't, `curl --location` does) and is slightly slower due to extra round-trip...

See https://github.com/cben/sandbox/tree/master/json directory for a working example (served at https://cben.github.io/sandbox/json/).

P.S. avoid more than one `index.*` and `README*` file in one dir; when I added a README.md alongside the index.json, the README won and got served at `json/`, so I had to rename it to something else.

Comment: This is the only working solution if you don't want the 'json' extension in the url, but still the applicatio/json header. ... Thanks!!

Comment: I should add, I had a file and directory with the same name, for example /json.json and a directory with index file eg /json/index.json and until I deleted the json.json file the file was not routable on the directory /json/

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding a code block on how to consume json from github:

```
function logResults(json) {
    console.log(json)
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cben/sandbox/master/json/index.json",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Please check the example at jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v_alishauskaite/dxm8cvkL/1/

Comment: Is it your intent to grab `json` from GitHub and not GitHub's Pages?... Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure that that's what `raw.githubusercontent` is pulling from, GitHub proper, in this case from your `master` branch.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does. :) I added this for curiosity. Not everyone knows that such an opportunity exists.

Comment: What is the rate limit for this?

Answer (score 1):

This type of url (eg : /posts) will only work with html files. You can name your json file **posts.html** and set its front matter like this :

```
---
layout: null
permalink: /posts/
---
{ "variable": "value" }
```

You will then reach your file at **/posts** or **/posts/**.

Only drawback is that the returned file is **/posts/index.html** which is served with `Content-Type: text/html` mime type and not the expected `application/json`.